# Remove background when using Rasterize in QGIS

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I used Rasterize (vector to raster). The result is shown below.

[image]

There is a bright yellow background around the map after I used Rasterize. I want to know how I can remove this. The value 0 can be given a whit colour, but I dont want to do that. 
So what can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert the 0's to NoData using GDAL Translate (**Raster -> Conversion -> Translate**):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found out that its another way to do this without creating a new layer. Choose transparency in layer properties. Under "No data value" there is a field called "Additional no data value", where zero is inserted. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of putting another option on the table, you could clip the areas you don't want by using `Raster > Extraction > Clip Raster by Mask Layer` (using a temporary scratch layer containing a polygon around the area you want to keep).